# when is this inequality feasible?

Tags: geometry, control-theory, mobius-transformation, stability-theory

I have the following inequality that has to hold for all frquencies $w$

$${\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{H\left( {jw} \right)}\\
1
\end{array}} \right]^*}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{ - 2mn}&{ - m - n}\\
{ - m - n}&{ - 2}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{H\left( {jw} \right)}\\
1
\end{array}} \right] \prec 0  \quad \quad(1)$$
where $H\left( {jw} \right) = \frac{{cb}}{{jw - a}} + d$. Now if we factorize the matrix

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{ - 2mn}&{ - m - n}\\
{ - m - n}&{ - 2}
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)}&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)}\\
0&1
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
2&0\\
0&{ - 2}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)}&0\\
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)}&1
\end{array}} \right]$$
Note that the matrix
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)}&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)}\\
0&1
\end{array}} \right]$$
could be considered as a mobius transformation
$$f\left( z \right) = \frac{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)z}}{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)z + 1}}$$
This mobius maps the circle symmetric about real axis and cuts it at $-1/m$ and $-1/n$ ($m\ge n>0$)to the unit circle. (1) is feasible if and only if the nyquist of $H(s)$ does not cut the circle symmetric about real axis and cuts it at $-1/m$ and $-1/n$. How could I prove that?

my attempt:

If I use
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{ - 2mn}&{ - m - n}\\
{ - m - n}&{ - 2}
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)}&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)}\\
0&1
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
2&0\\
0&{ - 2}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)}&0\\
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)}&1
\end{array}} \right]$$

and plug it, the inequality becomes

$${\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)H\left( {jw} \right)}\\
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)H\left( {jw} \right) + 1}
\end{array}} \right]^*}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
2&0\\
0&{ - 2}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)H\left( {jw} \right)}\\
{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)H\left( {jw} \right) + 1}
\end{array}} \right] \prec 0$$

If I could somehow conclude that the inequality is feasible whenever the nyquist of $f\left( {H\left( {jw} \right)} \right) = \frac{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m - n} \right)H\left( {jw} \right)}}{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {m + n} \right)H\left( {jw} \right) + 1}}$ lies outside the unit circle I can argue that the inverse mobius $f^{-1}(z)$ would mean the nyquist of $H(jw)$ lies outside the circle symmetric about real axis and cuts it at $-1/m$ and $-1/n$, but how could I conclude the former from the inequality in (2)?

Comment: This looks like a dissipativity condition. Maybe it would be easier to formulate this as an LMI for the state-space representation. If you really want to stay in the frequency domain then you could look at scale relative graphs to get some more geometric intuition about the Nyquist plots (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.13971.pdf, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.09788.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, this means that the graph of $H(j\omega)$ should live in some not-too-simple region of the complex plane.

To figure this out, let us consider the quadratic form

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
s\\
1
\end{bmatrix}^*\begin{bmatrix}
-2mn & -(m+n)\\
-(m+n) & -2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
s\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and check in what region of the complex plane this inequality is negative. Letting $s=\sigma+j\omega$ we get the inequality $$-2mn(\sigma^2+\omega^2)-2(m+n)\sigma-2<0.$$

Clearly, $\omega\ne0$ can only make this inequality more negative. So, the first idea would be to check for what values for $\sigma$ we have that the inequality holds for all $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$. Analyzing this polynomial, we find that it takes negative values for all $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$ provided that $$\sigma\notin[-1/m,-1/n].$$ This is described by the set

$$\mathcal{S}:=((-\infty,-1/m)\cup(-1/n,+\infty))\times\mathbb{R}.$$

Now we can look at when the right-hand side of $$mn\omega^2>-mn\sigma^2-(m+n)\sigma-1>0$$ is positive. This happens when $\sigma\in[-1/m,-1/n]$ and in this case, the term $\omega^2$ needs to be chosen such that the above inequality holds. This region is described as $$\mathcal{P}=\{(\sigma,\omega)\in[-1/m,-1/n]\times\mathbb{R}:mn\omega^2>-mn\sigma^2-(m+n)\sigma-1\}.$$

In summary, the region is described by the quadratic form is $\mathcal{S}\cup\mathcal{P}$. Getting back to your original problem, you will have to make sure that $H(j\omega)\in\mathcal{S}\cup\mathcal{P}$ for all $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$. There are many possible cases. Some are simple as they are structural, some others need more care.

For instance, if $a,b,c,d$ are such that $\min\{d,d-bc/a\}>-1/n$ or $\max\{d,d-bc/a\}<1/m$, then this is fine.

More complex cases arise when say $-bc/a+d>-1/n$ and $d<-1/m$. In such a case, we need to make sure that the curve does not enter the forbidden region.